# How to add search field in c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I don't know how to add a search field in the c# WPF environment. please help me. i will be grateful to you.

actually i have table in sql server named employee and i want to retrieve data from the table. like i want to search the employee by name. when i type the name in search field and click the search button it will show the result below later i can edit or delete the particular record.

advance thanks.

Comment: Can you show us your code and what you've tried already? See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: actually i have table in sql server named employee and i want to retrieve data from the table. like i want to search the employee by name. when  i type the name in search field and click the search button it will show the result below later i can edit or delete the particular record.

Answer (score 1):

Use TextBox and TextChanged event will fire when you perform operations in TextBox.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ABC"

        Width="500" Height="500">
    <TextBox  Width="300" Height="40" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"></TextBox>
</Window>
```

You have to generate the TextChanged event in CS file,

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // perform your operation here
        }
```

Comment: Not sure why you're being downvoted. Pretty sure you have to implement the search logic yourself in this manner, unless there's a third party control of course that OP is really asking for.

Comment: actually i have table in sql server named employee and i want to retrieve data from the table. like i want to search the employee by name. when  i type the name in search field and click the search button it will show the result below later i can edit or delete the particular record.

Comment: {
            EmployeeDataDataContext con = new EmployeeDataDataContext("Data Source=.\\SQLECPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\Employee.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Employee where Name like " +  textBox1.Text, con); // here something going wrong
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }